# adding variables to SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a list of columns in a DB.  I am trying to search for count of how many times an IP has been used per column.  When I put the variable ip_field into the query it doesn't seem to like it.  I have tried to use a single equals or double, it doesn't make a difference.  What is the proper syntax to use a variableI keep getting

> "filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

```
ip_fields = ["hub_wan1_public_ip", "ip_transit", "neighbor_ip"]
active_ip = 1.1.1.1


for ip_field in ip_fields:
    
    #have tried different variations
    #ip_count = db.session.query(SubInterfaces).filter_by(ip_field==active_ip).count()
    ip_count = db.session.query(SubInterfaces).filter_by(f"{ip_field}={active_ip}").count()
```

Comment: `active_ip = 1.1.1.1` throws "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Show us your **actual** code.

Comment: active_ip is a value in a dictionary.  When I print out the active_ip it print's the correct info, my error is not in the active_ip.  It is in the ip_field.  When I replace  the ip_field variable on the commented ip_count out line with "ip_transit" it works.  this is without touching active_ip  `active_ip = customer[key]`

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work.  Putting the variables into a dictionary and then unpacking it did the trick.

```
for ip_field in ip_fields:
            single_dict = {
                ip_field: active_ip
            }

            ip_count = db.session.query(SubInterfaces).filter_by(**single_dict).count()
```